# ESTbeaconMangerDelegate not calling functions in swift

Tags: swift, ibeacon

All,

I have added the header file and added the SDK for estimate beacons within Swift. But when i run this simple code the func didRangeBeacons is not called. Any ideas ?

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, ESTBeaconManagerDelegate {

    let BeaconManager : ESTBeaconManager = ESTBeaconManager()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

    // set beacon manager delegate
    BeaconManager.delegate = self
    var beaconRegion : ESTBeaconRegion = ESTBeaconRegion(proximityUUID: NSUUID(UUIDString: "B9407F30-F5F8-466E-AFF9-25556B57FE6D"), identifier: "Icy Marshmallow")
    BeaconManager.startRangingBeaconsInRegion(beaconRegion)

    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }


    func beaconManager(manager: ESTBeaconManager, didRangeBeacons: [ESTBeacon], inRegion: ESTBeaconRegion) {

        println("Found \(didRangeBeacons.count) in range");
    }
```

Comment: Is it because the bluetooth is not connecting because of the new is settings for bluetooth ? in the Plist file ?

Comment: If you are having this problem in IOS8 have a look at this https://community.estimote.com/hc/en-us/articles/203393036-Estimote-SDK-and-iOS-8-Location-Services

Answer (score 0):

make sure you login in to the estimotecloud using estimotecloudmanager. Place the login code in the AppDelegate Didlaunchwithoptin method.